# Parsing JSON from email header

Tags: android, json, gmail-api

I have got this kind of json data from a gmail header. How can i parse it to get the value of "delivered to" and "received" in android. Thanks in advance.

```
[
    {"name":"Delivered-To","value":"ayuka******l@gmail.com"},

    {"name":"Received","value":"by 10.140.22.233 with SMTP id 96csp129737qgn;        Tue, 12 Sep 2017 14:11:47 -0700 (PDT)"}, 

    {"name":"X-Google-Smtp-Source","value":"ADKCNb5EL+VcU9VEZ4HxoicjzSkTx8DxijwG+0LOR+My5P4fQoiAwNEY8LYBEN/kCq+ITzM43nDg"},

    {"name":"X-Received","value":"by 10.129.183.31 with SMTP id v31mr14525436ywh.24.1505250707382;        Tue, 12 Sep 2017 14:11:47 -0700 (PDT)"}   
]
```

Comment: Check out GSON: https://github.com/google/gson. It's very, very straightforward with any sort of JSON library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to get the JSON objects by index and then get the json field "name" in this case

```
JSONArray yourData = new JSONArray(jsonFromGmail); // Put your data inside a JSONArray  
String name = ""; 

try {
   for (int i = 0; i < yourData.length(); i++) {//Loop through your JSON array
         JSONObject jsonobj = null;
         jsonobj = yourData.getJSONObject(i); //Get JSONObjects by index
         System.out.println("name : " + i + " = " + jsonobj.getString("name"));
         name = jsonobj.getString("name");
         // Do whatever you want with the string
     }
 } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Worked fine. Just made a few changes to remove the numerous try catch.

Comment: Great to hear that, glad to help

Comment: Hey Andre....just encountered another problem...can you help me get the email body? I posted the question and no one has helped so far. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255530/getting-gmail-body-form-payload

Answer (score 1):

This works using Gson (see https://github.com/google/gson for installation instructions and documentation):

```
    String json = "[ {\"name\":\"Delivered-To\",\"value\":\"ayuka******l@gmail.com\"}, {\"name\":\"Received\",\"value\":\"by 10.140.22.233 with SMTP id 96csp129737qgn;        Tue, 12 Sep 2017 14:11:47 -0700 (PDT)\"}, {\"name\":\"X-Google-Smtp-Source\",\"value\":\"ADKCNb5EL+VcU9VEZ4HxoicjzSkTx8DxijwG+0LOR+My5P4fQoiAwNEY8LYBEN/kCq+ITzM43nDg\"}, {\"name\":\"X-Received\",\"value\":\"by 10.129.183.31 with SMTP id v31mr14525436ywh.24.1505250707382;        Tue, 12 Sep 2017 14:11:47 -0700 (PDT)\"}]";

    // parse the JSON string as an array
    JsonArray array = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonArray.class);
    String deliveredTo = "";
    String received = "";

    // iterate through the items of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        // parse each item as a JSON object, extract name and value from it
        JsonObject element = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        String name = element.get("name").getAsString();
        String value = element.get("value").getAsString();
            // look for the relevant fields in name; if we found them, set the according values
            if (name.equals("Delivered-To")) {
                deliveredTo = value;
            } else if (name.equals("Received")) {
                received = value;
            }
    }
    System.out.println("Delivered to: " + deliveredTo);
    System.out.println("Received: " + received);
```

Before you use this for production, you should of course add some checks for the validity of the Json and not take assumptions like I did here (e.g.: `name` and `value` exist on every item in the array).

Comment: Thanks. Am getting an error  "Expected a com.google.gson.JsonArray but was com.google.gson.JsonObject" at line 2 of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine.

```
JSONArray emailHeaderObj = null;
    String deliveredTo = " ";
    String received = " ";
    String Subject = " ";
    String from = "";
    try {
        emailHeaderObj = new JSONArray(emailHeaderString);

        for (int i = 0; i < emailHeaderObj.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject element = emailHeaderObj.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = element.getString("name");
            String value = element.getString("value");

            switch(name){
                case "Date":
                    received = value;
                    break;
                case "Subject":
                    Subject = value;
                    break;
                case "From":
                    from = value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```